# Flow cannot find Property in object type using switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have two types of chat messages in my chat application

```
export const UserType = "USER_MESSAGE";
export const SystemType = "SYSTEM_MESSAGE";
export type ChatType = typeof UserType | typeof SystemType;
```

I use a switch case to determine which type of message I am processing and depending on type choose to render its content.

This is where I run into trouble because depending on the `type` of the message, it will contain different `content` object structures.

```
const ChatMessages = ({ messages, style }: Input) => {
  // FLOW ERROR: Property `text`: Property not found in object type
  const renderUserMessage = (content: UserContent, i: number) => {
    return <p key={`message-${i}`}>
      <b>{content.userName}: </b>{content.text}
    </p>;
  };
  // FLOW ERROR: Property `info`: Property not found in object type
  const renderSystemMessage = (content: SystemContent, i: number) => {
    return <p key={`message-${i}`}>
      {content.info}
    </p>;
  };
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {messages.map((message, i) => {
        switch (message.type) {
          case UserType:
            return renderUserMessage(message.content, i);
          case SystemType:
            return renderSystemMessage(message.content, i);
          default:
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The rest of my types look like this

```
export type UserContent = {
  userName: string,
  text: string,
};

export type SystemContent = {
  info: string,
};

export type ChatContent =
  UserContent |
  SystemContent;

export type MessageType = {
  type: ChatType,
  content: ChatContent,
};
```

Changing the type definition from `UserContent` and `SystemContent` to a generic `Object` solves the problem, but that's not as strict as I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1669). There is a solution (or work around) to  simply reassign `message.type` to some variable before Switch statment, or  to swap the switch with an appropriate if chain.

So in your case this should work:

```
return (
    <div style={style}>
      {messages.map((message, i) => {
        let messageType = message.type;

        switch (messageType) {
          case UserType:
            return renderUserMessage(message.content, i);
          case SystemType:
            return renderSystemMessage(message.content, i);
          default:
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I still get the same error :(